# slimv not loading on *.lisp files in vim

Tags: linux, vim, lisp, slime, ftplugin

I installed slimv.vim (first through yaourt on Archlinux and then through vimana) and via both methods, slimv.vim doesn't load when I open a lisp file.  I've scoured google results for debugging help, and here's what I have checked so far:

- `:scriptnames` does not show `slimv.vim`, so it's not being loaded at all
- `:filetype` shows all options set to ON
- `:set rtp?` shows `~/.vim` as the first entry
- vim was compiled with python, shows `+python`
- `slimv.vim` and related files are all in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`
- `:echo $HOME` shows the correct home directory
- `slimv.vim` is of `filetype=unix`
- I've tried both with and without `let g:slimv_python = 'python2'` in `.vimrc`, as suggested by the AUR comments for slimv
- `:messages` shows nothing
- `:set ft?` shows that the file is recognized as lisp

I don't have any other plugins, so it's possible that this is a general vim issue and I can't tell.  What should I try next?

Answer (score 3):

Even if :filetype shows all options set to ON, maybe they are set too late (paredit.vim sets them), so I suggest to write this in your .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

Also you can set verbose mode by running vim with the -V10 option:

```
vim -V10 test.lisp
```

This prints log info on the scripts searched and sourced.

Slimv comes with paredit.vim that is a general (not a filetype) plugin, so it should be loaded for all filetypes. Check if it is loaded via

```
:echo g:paredit_loaded
```

You may also want to try to install another vim plugin just to test if it's a general vim problem or something related to Slimv.

EDIT: filetype plugins either need to have the same name as the filetype itself (e.g. lisp.vim) or they need to reside in a subdirectory having the same name as the filetype. Slimv uses the latter logic, so make sure that there is a lisp subdirectory containing slimv-lisp.vim:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/lisp/slimv-lisp.vim
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say where your problem is exactly but first I would check that your filetype is recognized properly. `:set ft?` should output something like `filetype=lisp`

After that you could check `:messages` for any error messages.

Comment: ft? shows filetype=lisp, and :messages shows nothing.  (I've put that info in the original post)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually fixed this issue by uninstalling slimv.vim and manually removing the file named `lisp` from `~/.vim/ftplugin/`, then reinstalling with vimana.  It's working great, now.  Thanks for helping me through it!